# Can't debug MVC4 project

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

Relatively new to mvc. I have what I consider a strangely architected project that I inherited after someone left my company. There are two "service layers". The main layer is an MVC 4 project which expects a REST query. Here is how it works:

1. An asp.net page in another project allows the user to enter a REST query. The same asp.net page calls serviceRequest.DownloadString with the REST query that was entered.
2. This results in a call to a DelegatingHandler in the mvc 4 project. This DelegatingHandler does some validation of the headers sent with the request. If the data is correct, the DelegatingHandler calls base.SendAsync with the same REST query that was passed in to the DelegatingHandler.
3. This activates the controller in the mvc 4 project that is called by the REST query. If it is working, the mvc 4 project returns xml.

4, To do much of the work the controller calls methods from a wcf project.

What is happening is that this architecture works fine if run inside visual studio. It also runs fine if the two service layers (the mvc 4 and wcf projects) are deployed to IIS applications on my local machine.

The problem occurs when the service layers are deployed to two seperate machines, one in the dmz and one on a macine inside the firewall. It returns a 500.

I used fiddler and fixed one problem that had to do with connection strings. Once that was done I still got the 500 as a result but no other information. In this case running fiddler again only confirmed that I was receiving a 500. I have tried:

1. puting trace code in the configs of both service layers
2. using an existing function in the wcf layer to write some debug information to a table from the controller.

I realize that I might not have put in the trace code in the mvc and wcf config files but it does seem to be simply bypassing the mvc 4 project altogether. I also notice some information on being able to use debug.write. Is this a viable option.

None of these two steps has brought me any closer to solving the problem. I am getting the impression that the mvc 4 code is never getting called at all and the error is occuring when the serviceRequest.DownloadString is called to bring up the DelegatingHandler. However I don't know where to look to see if I'm right. Is there a spot in the code (e.g and event) that I could use to follow the code from when it leaves the asp.net page and tries to go to the mvc 4 project?

What is the best way to debug this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Fig0000

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but looks like the error returned is not shown because you are not running on localhost. And the error might be for some config files wrong or anything actually.

Can you try to run the application isolated (maybe creating a dummy method in each and if that works, make the internal call (fake / mock) so you can see what's the actual problem.

OR
you can try to let mvc to display all error even on remote. You can do this on web.config :

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I managed to do some tracing. It looks like the API is firing the Application_Start event but not the controller. This only happens in when the app is deployed to a remote server. I put a trace in the  OnException event of the api which didn't seem to fire. I guess I need to find some other events that occur after the Application_Start(). Any advice would be appreciated. What would stop the controller from firing?

Comment: I just traced through all of the request events and they all fired. Still the controller is not firing.

Comment: url rewrite, static mime types, global or controller attributes, routing on web config. can be many things actually.